# Why am I not able to create a custom intent asking for 2 texts?

Tags: android, actions-on-google, app-actions

I have a custom intent to receive 2 text parameters from the Google Assistant. But the Assistant will not launch my app. I have tried with just one and it works correctly. The problem is when I add a second text parameter. I have tried with another data type and it works. For example, if I ask for a text and a number it works good. If I ask for a text and a time it works, too. BUT if i ask for a text and a text, then it doesn't. Any help here please?
This is my intent in the actions.xml file:

```
<action intentName="custom.actions.intent.MyName" queryPatterns="@array/MyExampleStrings">
   <!-- Define parameters -->
   <parameter name="textA" type="https://schema.org/Text" />
   <parameter name="textB" type="https://schema.org/Text" />

   <!-- Define fulfillment -->
   <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://my.site.com/{?FirstText,SecondText}">
      <parameter-mapping intentParameter="textA" urlParameter="FirstText" />
      <parameter-mapping intentParameter="textB" urlParameter="SecondText" />
   </fulfillment>
</action>
```

MyExampleStrings is something like this "Bake $textA using $textB" for example "Bake spaghetti with tomato".

As I said before it works with a different data types. This next example I changed the second text for a number and it works:

```
<action intentName="custom.actions.intent.MyName" queryPatterns="@array/MyExampleStrings">
   <!-- Define parameters -->
   <parameter name="textA" type="https://schema.org/Text" />
   <parameter name="textB" type="https://schema.org/Number" /> <--NUMBER!

   <!-- Define fulfillment -->
   <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://my.site.com/{?FirstText,SecondText}">
      <parameter-mapping intentParameter="textA" urlParameter="FirstText" />
      <parameter-mapping intentParameter="textB" urlParameter="SecondText" />
   </fulfillment>
</action>
```

In this case if I say something like "Bake spaghetti with 4" it works.
Why cannot I have two strings???
Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google's assistance and this is not a solution but rather a workaround that might work for you, until you find a better one. Why not send a single text and add a special separator inside? Like, spaghetti@Tomatoes or something of the sort, and once you get the text in your activity just split by this char and use the values.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried to replicate the issue using your example above, but it works as intended on my end. Both fields are included as part of the intent?.data field. So, in my case, it looks like this:

```
https://todo.myapp.com/custom-intents?FirstText=Example123&SecondText=Example222
```

Could you further elaborate on how you're retrieving the query param?

As a general recommendation a log statement in your onCreate function in of activity should provide these details:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Timber.tag(TAG).d("======= debugging data =========" + intent?.data)
}
```

Comment: Did you check it using the real Google Assistant or using the App Actions Test Tool? It fails only in the real Assistant. I cannot give you right now a log but it will display something like in the next comment:

Comment: todo.myapp.com/custom-intents?FirstText=Example123%20with%20Example222&SecondText=Example222

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarification about Assistant. That's correct, this is a known issue, and a fix is underway. I will keep you posted here.

Comment: Thanks. How do you know it is a known issue? Is it published anywhere?

Comment: Not yet. I worked for the Assistant DevRel team. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot Diego. What about this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64528702/1363087 Is it also a known bug?

Comment: Don't know. Will look into this one too.

Comment: @Diego can you plz check on this issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65068572/app-action-working-via-app-action-tool-plugin-but-not-with-voice-command-in-goog] Whether it is the issue is from google end or are we missing anything from our end.

Comment: This should be fixed. Please try again.

@Rathish the team is looking into that one. Stay tuned and please comment there instead. Thanks!