# App Action working via App Action Tool Plugin but not with voice command in Google Assistant Screen

Tags: android, actions-on-google, app-actions

1. Logged in using the same credentials (Android Studio, Google Console, Real Device - Samsung s10+) and Device language set to EN-US.
2. Selected App Action tool plugin from the tools menu
3. Gave invocation name (todo app) and locale to En-US
4. Changed default feature "History" with my command (In my case "Open active tasks in todo app")
5. Tapped on Update Preview.
6. Once the preview updated, Run the command via the AATT tool, it's working perfectly.
7. Once the preview updated successfully, Opened the Google Assistant on a Real device and gave a voice command (Open **active tasks** in todo app), but it's showing web results on the Assistant screen instead of showing my App. Attached screenshot for reference.

[image]

Please let me know if I'm missing anything here.

Comment: Have you check if the Google Assistant device is using the same Google Account as the one you are using for development? Dev actions are not publicly available and can only be used on devices that use the same email.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what you're doing in step 7.  Indicate the assistant heard exactly that (take a screenshot and show it here so we can verify it), and make sure that would match up with the intent you expect it to trigger.

Comment: @Jordi Yes i'm using the same account in all 3 places(Device, Android Studio, google console)

Comment: @Jordi if I try to invoke "Open **active task** in todo app" from the AATT tool, I could able to navigate to the particular screen in my app, but if I use the same phrase from the google assistant screen through voice/text it's not navigating to the app instead I'm getting web results. What I noticed is if we use a single verb like "open **active** in todo app" at times it's navigating inside the app. So my doubt is, do we need to use the phrases **"Open "verb" in "appname"** will only work

Comment: @Jordi Where to add phrases? Inside android app? and how to train the models?

Comment: Sorry I got things mixed up, that isn't avaialable for App Actions

Answer (score 1):

I could able to achieve it using GET_THINGS Built-In Intent. OPEN_APP Intent supports only a single word. If your requirement is to say multiple words like "Show **alerts for today** in TestApp", then we can use GET_THINGS Intent, which supports multiple words.